# C# DBML connection String fails while set

Tags: c#, dbml

The connection string to my db is set in the Web.config for my project:

```
<connectionStrings>
      <add name="ServiceConnectionString" 
           connectionString="Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress;Initial 
              Catalog=Service;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

This is a correct configuration and when I execute stored procedures from the server explorer they return correctly as expected.

My problem stems from when I try to access this db inline with such a call as (AddProduct returns an int):

```
return new serviceSQLDataContext()
     .AddProduct(name, category, price, quantity);
```

Which fails on this line:

```
base(global::System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
    .ConnectionStrings["ServiceConnectionString"]
       .ConnectionString, mappingSource)
```

With the first parameter triggering a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception.

How is this possible seeing as in my Web.config I have the correct connection string specified? And is there a solution?